# How can I paste image to skype by URI (such as Line)

Tags: ios, xcode

How to write a code that use Skype URI scheme to paste image by my app(ios)?

Such as many apps can paste image to Line, e.g., FB... (through URI or SLComposeViewController, etc)

The point is "to paste image", not text.